# Cannot connect to RPi2 if wlan is configured

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet

I am setting up a Raspberry Pi 2 as an access point within my home office.  I have connected the ethernet and configured the WLAN.  I have not yet setup `hostapd` as I have connectivity problems.

If the wlan interface is up it is not possible to connect to the Pi in anyway, however if I issue `ifconfig wlan0 down` then I am able to connect using SSH.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.50.252
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(The `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory is empty).

I cannot see what the issue is at all.  `ifconfig` reports that everything is OK, but when `wlan0` is up it is not possible to connect.  I am sure I am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I realise my mistake, I needed to use a bridge as I was connecting to the same network with 2 different devices.  Now my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo wlan
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
```

I can now access the PI and both interfaces are up.